# backup database using mysqldump with php not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-backup

please i want to backup my database using php.
i have tried many answered question on this similar problem but still not working.

```
$username = "***";
$password = '******';
$database = 'mydatabase';
$filename = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s") . ".sql";


exec("(/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt -u$username -p$password $database> $filename) 2>&1", $output, $result);

var_dump($result);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($output);
echo "<br />";
```

this is the response

```
int(1) 
array(0) { }
```

Comment: There would be no output though, you are writing to a file aren't you? The `.sql` doesn't get created?

Comment: Given code is working properly.
It will create .sql file if you have write permission on executing directory.
It will throw warning related to passing password in CLI which can be removed by using .cnf file.

Comment: There would be no output though, correct. 
2>&1 is redirecting the error output in the standard, since you already redirected the standard output with >$filename it looks correct that in case of  you are not seing nothing , perhaps you need to use a tee to have something in the output.
The standard linux command return is 0 for successfull, other values means an error and you are getting 1 but the only place where an error is shown will be inside the file redirected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
exec( '/usr/bin/mysqldump --user="'.$username .'" --password="'.$password .'" "'.$database .'" > "'.$filename .'"' );
```